# Let K(2,3) have bipartition B⋃W where B={a,b} and W={x,y,z}

Tags: graph-theory, bipartite-graphs

Why in a spanning tree of K(2,3) there must be precisely one of the vertices of {x,y,z} joined to both "a" and "b" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A spanning tree contains all vertices, but there is no edge between $a$ and $b$, so at least one vertex of $W$ must be connected to both.
If they were connected to 2 vertices from $W$, it would contain a circle.